# Pair devices via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

In my app i need to connect some bluetooth device and send some string data to it. So i generate an actionbar item, which by click on it, some steps accur:
1. Bluetooth turns on (If it is cuurently off)
2. Device set to discoverable
3. By some delay, List of paired devices displays on screen.

now my question is: "How can I connect my mobile to one of paired list?!"
I know I should use setOnItemClickListener , but how?  If I should generate some function for "CONNECT" ? here is my code:

In MainActivity:

```
    private BluetoothAdapter BA;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;
    ListView lv;
```

In onCreate:

```
    BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

In my onOptionsItemSelected:

```
case R.id.action_bluetooth:


                if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth Turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
                    public void onFinish() {
                        Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);
                    }

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }
                }.start();


                new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // When timer is finished
                        // Execute your code here
                        showBluetoothListView();
                    }

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }
                }.start();

                return true;
```

In Function showBluetoothListView() :

```
public void showBluetoothListView (){
        final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        d.setTitle("Bluetooth Paired Devices");
        d.setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_list);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) d.findViewById(R.id.bluetoothlistView);
        pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
            list.add(bt.getName());

        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        d.show();
    }
```